# Gunicorn Internal Server Errors

Tags: python, django, deployment, gunicorn

I have a Gunicorn server running a Django application which has a tendency to crash quite frequently. Unfortunately when it crashes all the Gunicorn workers go down simultaneously and silently bypass Django's and django-sentry's logging. All the workers return "Internal Server Error" but the arbiter does not crash so supervisord does not register it as a crash and thus does not restart the process.

My question is, is there a way to hook onto a Gunicorn worker crash and possibly send an email or do a logging statement? Secondly is there a way to get supervisord to restart Gunicorn server that is returning nothing but 500's?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste here any logs? Gunicorn log and supervisord/gunicorn log? If everything is default, logs form supervisord should be in /tmp

Comment: Unfortunately I can't due to company policy, but there are logging statements formed in /tmp/supervisord but they don't register anything useful when the gunicorn workers crash since the whole server isn't crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using zc.buildout. Here is an example using plugin Superlance for supervisord with buildout:

```
[supervisor]
recipe = collective.recipe.supervisor
plugins =
   superlance
...
programs =
     10 zeo ${zeo:location}/bin/runzeo ${zeo:location}
     20 instance1 ${instance1:location}/bin/runzope ${instance1:location} true
...
eventlisteners =
     Memmon TICK_60 ${buildout:bin-directory}/memmon [-p instance1=200MB]
     HttpOk TICK_60 ${buildout:bin-directory}/httpok [-p instance1 -t 20 http://localhost:8080/]
```

Which will do http request every 20 seconds and restart process if it fails.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.supervisor/0.16

Comment: If you are not already using zc.buildout, then you don't need to use it to run superlance. see their pypi page for more info. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/superlance

Comment: Yes superlance is exactly what I needed. Thanks!